# How to link two separate flutter applications with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Work on an app like uber for a graduation project with flutter
There will be two separate applications, one for the driver and another for the user, and we use firebase. How do I make the user application send the driver data such as: address, and so on, to be in contact between the two applications in general
please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add Firebase to the two applications. And make sure you have the same models class (at least a common base).

Eg. You share the same `graduation.dart` file targetting same firestore collections named `graduations`. So you will be able to manipulate *graduations collection documents* in the two applications.